# How can I populate my form inside Bootstrap 3 modals upon table edit button click?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am new to this web development kind of thing. This is really driving me crazy over the past week. I want to populate my form inside my modal, I've been reading forums and tutorials to no avail. I read that you need something like AJAX which I have no experience with so if the answer's within that field I would really appreciate it if you can explain it to a beginner like me.
** Anyway here is my table**

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:center;"> ITEM CODE </th>
                            <th style="text-align:center;"> NAME </th>
                            <th style="text-align:center;"> SIZE </th>
                            <th style="text-align:center;"> COLOR </th>
                            <th style="text-align:center;"> ACTION </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                        include('connect.php');
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$row['itemcode'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$row['name'].'</div></td>';
                                echo '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$row['size'].'</div></td>';
                                echo '<td style="text-align:center;">'.$row['color'].'</div></td>';
                                echo '<td style="text-align:center;"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#">EDIT</a></td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                            }

                        ?> 
                    </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have an edit button linking to my modal on that last td tag right there.

**Now here is my modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="largeModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <?php
        include('connect.php');
        $itemcode=$_GET['itemcode'];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where itemcode='$itemcode'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
               $name=$row['name'];
               $size=$_GET['size'];
               $color=$_GET['color'];
            }
        ?>      

         <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                     <h1 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Products</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Product name" value="<? echo $name;?>"></input>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Product size" value="<? echo $size;?>"></input>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Product color" value="<? echo $color;?>"></input>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a href="searchresult.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">DO IT!</a>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

I am probably doing this the wrong way and I am probably missing something fundamental. If anyone will help please kindly explain to me what you did I am still not use to web developing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I didnt give your code a look but as you have said that you have to populate your form in the modal by the value taken from anywhere etc database there are three ways ... Lets have a look at them

**(1) AJAX and Jquery**

you're gonna have to use it if you want to dynamically load your your data inside the form in the modal.

**How can you do it?**

add an onclick event to the button that is calling the modal and call a function like this

```
<button data-target = "... etc .."   onclick = "load_my_form()"></button>

function load_my_form()
{
$.get("get_form_data.php" , function(result){

$(".my_foarm_loading_modal").html(result); // add this class to the body of the modal

});
}
```

Now in your php page echo all the data within the form fields and it will work

**(2) Link to New Page**

Make your modal calling button a link that takes you to the next page where you would write php code inside your modal body and then make a custom call to your modal in javascript so that it shows up when the page finishes loading ...

```
("#mymodal").show();
```

**Redirection**

you can make your modal calling div a link that calls a php page then echo all the data within form fields and add it to a string and send send that string back to your calling page and in the body of the modal write following code

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

if(isset($_GET['your_return_var_name']))
{
echo $_GET['your_return_var_name'];
}

?>
```

Hope it helps ...

Answer (score 0):

The "proper" way would be to use ajax to populate the form.

---

You can explicitly create the modal each time based on an ajax response:

```
$('#activate').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/ajax/form/populator',
      data: {id:  },
      success: function(formdata) {
        createModal(formdata)
      }
    });
});
```

Or, better, is that you create a function in you main.js that will do this for you:

```
$('#activate').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    showDialog('/ajax/form/populator', 'My super awesome form');
    return false;
});
```

It is important to note:

> Any HTML populated via ajax will need event handlers assigned after it is populated or the event will need to be based of the document (ie submit button).